# Linq2sql update each row in a huge table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a huge table (over 80M rows) and I created a model from the DB using linq2sql. I loop over the table (all 80M rows) and update each row with several values. I have done the most to optimize the code around the linq2sql code, but it looks like the `db.SaveChanges()` method hangs on the first update.

My code looks something like this (I`m paraphrasing for readability):

```
using(MessageListCtx db = new MessageListCtx())
{
   foreach(var message in db.MessageList.OrderByDescending(e => e.RecordId))
   {
      message.hashCode = Hasher.GenerateHash(message.name);
      db.SubmitChanges();
   }
}
```

I'm guessing that the issue is that when I call `db.SubmitChanges();` all objects in the context are iterated for changes, which takes a while with over 80M objects, but I have no idea how to get around this.

I was thinking about paging the results using a `for` loop. Something like: `db.MessageList.Skip(i).Take(1000)`. But I`d rather an out-of-the-box solution, if one exists.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Move your submit after the for loop. You hit the DB each time.

Comment: @paqogomez - Yes, I know. My thinking was that if I write the chnages to the DB with each iteration, that will be better for performance. Since Linq2Sql will generate a discrete `UPDATE` command for each object anyway, I thought that would be the better way to go.

Comment: The overhead connecting to the database in each loop is what is killing you.  After the for each it will run all the updates at once... still might be a problem, but its a DB problem

Comment: @paqogomez Incorrect. It is a L2S state tracking problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Forget it**

Linq 2sql is not made for batch operations. You really need to move this to a set operated level to get some performance.

No matter what you do, you will get individual update statements so no performance.

I guess the fastest way is to do something like this:

- use the foreach without change tracking (`ObjectTrackingEnabled = false` )
- build an in-memory data structure with hashes
- use sqlbulkcopy to bulk insert into a staging table (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)
- use an 'old school' update statement to update you large table

And I guess still with this approach you might want to buffer this into 100k records at a time

Comment: So what is the alternative?

Comment: @EladLachmi  combination of Linq and SqlBulkCopy perhaps; see updated answer

Comment: Yes, this is almost exactly what I am doing right now. It is up to 4M rows now. With any other approach memory would max out at around 500K rows. The only difference between your approach and what I am doing right now, is that I am using an SqlReader to read the rows one by one.

Comment: Maybe using linq2sql for the read would be even better, but since this is a one off data conversion job, it's good enough with the `SqlReader`.

Answer (score -1):

The poor performance comes from the large amount of object being tracked. That needs to be removed.

Try the following:

- read your records using one context with no state tracking
- write each update using a separate write context, and attach your entity to it before calling SaveChanges